# c++ stl correct parameters to priority_queue

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, dijkstra

Below is the code snippet which is incorrect.

I want to implement dijkstra using priority queue stl of c++. But i cant figure out the right syntax for using this priority_queue with edge class. I want to put edge to priority_queue with based on weights.

```
class edge{
public: 
    int src;
    int dest;
    int wt;
};

class comp {
bool operator() (int a, int b) {
    if(a<=b){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
   }
};


priority_queue<int,edge,comp> check;

edge e1,e2,e3;
e1.dest=1;
e2.dest=2;
e3.dest=3;
```

Comment: Post a [mcve], and the comparison must be a *strict weak ordering*.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think the problem was that he couldn't post a complete verifiable example because he didn't know the (admittedly convoluted, for a beginner) syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

class edge{
public:
    int src;
    int dest;
    int wt;
};

struct less_weight {
    bool operator() (const edge& a, const edge& b) {
        return a.wt < b.wt;
    }
};

struct greater_weight {
    bool operator() (const edge& a, const edge& b) {
        return a.wt > b.wt;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<int,std::vector<edge>,less_weight> prioritise_higher_weights;
    prioritise_higher_weights.push(edge{0, 1, 1 });
    prioritise_higher_weights.push(edge{1, 2, 2 });
    prioritise_higher_weights.push(edge{2, 3, 3 });

    std::priority_queue<int,std::vector<edge>,greater_weight> prioritise_lower_weights;
    prioritise_lower_weights.push(edge{0, 1, 1 });
    prioritise_lower_weights.push(edge{1, 2, 2 });
    prioritise_lower_weights.push(edge{2, 3, 3 });

    std::cout << prioritise_higher_weights.top().wt << std::endl;
    std::cout << prioritise_lower_weights.top().wt << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
3
1
```

Note how priority queue orders by the inverse of the given predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Read the **[spec for priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)** first. Seriously, read it.

Note that the first template param is the type you want to store, so if you want to store `Edge`s, then `Edge` should be you first parameter.

The second template param is the container the `priority_queue` will use underneath to store the values you provide. By default, is `std::vector` and I think is good enough for the demo purposes.

The third template param is the comparator to use in comparing *the values you will be storing* in the queue. Since you are storing `Edge`s, you need a comparator class able to compare `Edge` instances, not `int`s.

The above being said, try this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

class Edge{
public:
    int src;
    int dest;
    int wt;
};

struct comp {
  // note the use of references
  bool operator() (const Edge& a, const Edge& b) {
    // comparison by edge weights
    return a.wt < b.wt;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Edge> storage;
  comp compare;
  std::priority_queue<Edge, std::vector<Edge>, comp> check(compare);

  Edge e1,e2,e3;
  e1.wt=1; e1.src=1; e1.dest=2;
  e2.wt=2; e2.src=1; e2.dest=2;
  e3.wt=3; e3.src=2; e3.dest=3;

  check.push(e1);
  // pushing the maximum in the middle, let's see where it gets
  check.push(e3);
  check.push(e2);

  // let's see what's on top
  const Edge& top=check.top();
  std::cout << "weight: "<< top.wt 
            << " src:" << top.src 
            << " dest:" << top.dest << std::endl; // got the maximum on top
}
```